# Diagonalize a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

let $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1&2&3\\2&3&4\\3&4&5 \end{array}\right)$$

I need to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^tAP$ is a diagonal matrix and it's main diagonal may have only the terms from the set $\{ 1,-1,0 \}$

I'd be glad if you could explain to me how to solve this. I haven't found the right theorem/algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think, are the diagonal components to $A$?

Comment: $|A|=0$  so matrix is not rank 3 (rank=2 <3) ,there is not enough rational eigenvalue

Comment: check Takagi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Takagi.27s_factorization

Comment: also check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246065/factorization-of-an-invertible-symmetric-matrix/246092#246092

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This trick is due to Hermite. It is especially useful when you have a symmetric matrix of integers. First, we write a certain function in three variables,
$$ f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 3 y^2 + 5 z^2 + 8 yz+ 6 zx +4xy,  $$ because this is exactly the result of calculating $v^t A v,$ with
$$
v =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In order to clear the terms with $x,$ we write
$$ (x + 2 y + 3 z)^2 =   x^2 + 4 y^2 + 9 z^2 + 12 yz+ 6 zx +4xy.  $$
So far,
$$ f(x,y,z) -  (x + 2 y + 3 z)^2 = -y^2 - 4 z^2 - 4 y z.  $$
Next we clear all $y,$ 
$$ (y + 2 z)^2 = y^2 + 4 z^2 + 4 y z,  $$ and
$$  f(x,y,z) -  (x + 2 y + 3 z)^2 +  (y + 2 z)^2 = 0,  $$
$$ \color{red}{ f(x,y,z) =  (x + 2 y + 3 z)^2 -  (y + 2 z)^2 }.  $$

The matrix multiplication that this shows is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$
That is actually the right way to do it.

However, I see that someone asked for invertible $P,$ despite non-full rank. Also can be done, and easily:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The effect of this is to add $0$ to the function in the shape of $0z^2.$

ADDED: looking at the question again, we do need the extra $1$ in the lower right, because the matrix $P$ requested is actually the inverse of the on I display above. Life goes on.

Comment: That's really nice, I've never heard about that before. Still, for the sake of a more general result,one could at least mention the spectral theorem. A bigger picture certainly doesn't harm...

Answer (score 2):

I never remember exactly how this goes, so let's think about it.

Since $1,-,1,0$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, there exists vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ such that
$$
Av_1=v_1,\ \ Av_2=-v_2,\ \ Av_3=0.
$$
Also, the fact that $A$ is symmetric guarantees that 
$$
v_1^tv_2=v_1^tv_3=v_2^tv_3=0.
$$
If we take $P=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}$, then
$$
AP=\begin{bmatrix}Av_1&Av_2&Av_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&-v_2&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
P^tAP=\begin{bmatrix}v_1^t\\ v_2^t\\ v_3^t\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}v_1&-v_2&0\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1^tv_1&-v_1^tv_2&0\\ v_2^tv_1&-v_2^tv_2&0\\ v_3^tv_1&-v_3^tv_2&0
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1^tv_1&0&0\\ 0&-v_2^tv_2&0\\ 0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So if we take $v_1$ and $v_2$ to be unit vectors, then $P=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

Please follow the procedure, outlined here with an example: http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/diagonal/diagonal.html

Update your question with the results of your work and post a comment to this response. I will be happy to check your work for you.